# Hosting Docusaurus as subfolder in root domain. NGINX Proxy for Docusaurus drops /docs path on page refresh

Tags: docusaurus

I'm encountering a routing issue with my Docusaurus site, which is in Docs-only mode and is served under the /docs path on my domain through NGINX. While navigating between pages works as expected, refreshing any page causes the URL to change by dropping the /docs path, leading to a 404 Not Found error.

Here's my NGINX configuration:

```
server {
    # ... other server configurations ...

    location /docs {
      proxy_set_header Host "example.pages.dev";
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass https://example.pages.dev/;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    # ... other location blocks or server configurations ...
}
```

Behavior Observed:

- Navigating between pages on https://example.com/docs works correctly.
- Upon refreshing any page or access the page directly, the browser URL changes to exclude `/docs` (e.g., https://example.com/page), resulting in a 404 error.

Key Points:

- Docusaurus Configuration: `baseUrl` in docusaurus.config.js is set to `/docs/`.
- Docusaurus Configuration: `routeBasePath` in docusaurus.config.js is set to `/`.

Objective: To ensure that the Docusaurus site under `/docs` retains the correct URL structure even after a page refresh or access directly.

Is there a specific NGINX directive or a Docusaurus configuration I might be missing that could resolve this URL change on refresh?

Any insights or suggestions to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATES:**
Apparently the issue is due to 3 redirects happening when it is missing a trailing slash.

https://example.com/docs/page will redirect to https://example.com/docs/page/ which than redirect to remove the `/docs/`

Adding Docusaurus Configuration: `trailingSlash: false`  in docusaurus.config.js does the trick and url without trailing slash doesn't get redirect. But if access https://example.com/docs/page/ directly will trigger the same issue of remove the `/docs/`.

Adding this rule `rewrite ^/docs/(.*)/$ /docs/$1 permanent;` does the trick of preventing redirect when there is a trailng slash.